# How to add nonce attribute to script tags using webpack 5

Tags: webpack, thymeleaf, content-security-policy, webpack-5

I am using webpack 5 with `HtmlWebpackPlugin` to build my frontend SPA.

I need to add `nonce` attribute to `<script ...` tags injected by `HtmlWebpackPlugin`.

How do I do it?

Extra question: after that I am using this pages as Thymeleaf templates before serving. How do I inject `nonce` value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were using webpack 4, there is plenty of fish in the sea — just use any plugin which injects attributes, such as [script-ext-html-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/numical/script-ext-html-webpack-plugin) or [html-webpack-inject-attributes-plugin](https://github.com/dyw934854565/html-webpack-inject-attributes-plugin)

However, most of the plugins mentioned above do not work with webpack 5. The workaround is to use the `HtmlWebpackPlugin` [templates](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin#writing-your-own-templates).

1. Set `inject` to `false` in `HtmlWebpackPlugin` options specified in `webpack.config`.
2. In template add the following code which will insert all the generated scripts into resulting file:

```html
    <% for (key in htmlWebpackPlugin.files.js) { %>
      <script type="text/javascript" defer="defer" src="<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.files.js[key] %>"></script>
    <% } %>
```

3. Add all the necessary attributes in `script`. Thymeleaf example:

```html
    <% for (key in htmlWebpackPlugin.files.js) { %>
      <script type="text/javascript" defer="defer" th:attr="nonce=${cspNonce}" src="<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.files.js[key] %>"></script>
    <% } %>
```

Answer based on [github post](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/issues/538#issuecomment-270340587)